# How get acess to data Audiences of Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, analytics, firebase-analytics

I need any log or data of Audiences by Big Query, how to consult this in a non-manual way through events? I need firebase analytics groups and audience data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect the Analytics from your Firebase project to BigQuery, only the raw events are exported to BigQuery. Neither audience definitions, not audience membership are exported to BigQuery.

So if you want to see audiences in your BigQuery based reports, you'll have to (re)create both the audience definitions and memberships there.

---

Update: There **is** now a way to [import external segments back *into* Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/import-segments). So if you make changes to your audience definitions outside of Firebase, you can now import those into Firebase, and target them with FCM, Remote Config, etc.