# How can I send an email campaign to a Firebase audience?

Tags: firebase

Is there a way to send an email to members of my Firebase audience?
I can't seem to find a way to programmatically interact with my audiences; I would like to send them email campaigns in addition to Cloud Messaging.

My problem is that seemingly I can't access who is in my audience.
Similarly is there a way to provide custom content (not Remote Config) in my web app based on Audience membership - use the Audience membership for in-app segmentation?

Interested in any solution, workaround, brainstorming idea you may have.

I am lost on this and starting to wonder if Audiences can't be used this way at all.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you also use Firebase Authentication? Otherwise, how do you get user's email and get it associated with Audience membership?

Comment: Yes, we do, all users are authenticated, we do have their email addresses and they are opt-in. This is a PWA and for our audiences email is the primary form of preferred communication.

Comment: There is no API to get audiences *from* Firebase/Google Analytics. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043275/how-get-acess-to-data-audiences-of-firebase-analytics. There is nowadays a way to import external audiences back into Firebase, but that's not what you're looking for: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/import-segments